# Создать функцию для всех объектов

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать такое же для всех изображений находящихся на странице, а не только для одного изображения?

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}

.modal-content,
#caption {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="myImg" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы в коде использовали в конце `var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];`

А именно там-то и полезнее был бы id, вместо class))

А вот клик - как раз нужно привязать к классу, а не к id. После getElementsByClassName... это число внутри `[0]` показывает номер элемента, среди элементов с этим классом. Второй такой элемент можно получить через `[1]`, третий `[2]`. Вот и нужно взять все эти элементы и привязать к ним клик. Но чтобы не переписать всё вручную, используют цикл for, который кругами будет выполнять написанное внутри сперва для номера 0, потом для 1, потом 2 и т.п.

Про цикл for() чуть подробнее описал [Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/980669/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7-25-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%83/980679#980679)

[JsFiddle >>](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/z9qyf1a8/)

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("modal-content");
var caption = document.getElementById("caption");

var img = document.getElementsByClassName("myImg");
for(var i = 0; i < img.length; i++){
  //Где-нибудь почитайте про addEventListener... он полезнее чем onclick
  img[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    caption.innerHTML = this.alt;
  });
}
  

document.getElementById("close").onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.myImg:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#myModal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

#modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}

#modal-content,
#caption {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}

#close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#close:hover,
#close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="myImg" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">

<img class="myImg" src="https://gyazo.com/03fcf3c9a86b00f85f98fa343149e740.png" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span id="close">&times;</span>
  <img id="modal-content">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

Я местами подменил ваш CSS-селекторы, и сам запутался где-что. Перепроверьте))

А W3Schools - в целом полезный сайт, чтобы подсматривать как работают те или иные фишки. Но у них в готовых примерах больно уж часто всетрчается какашко-код))