# Второе модальное окно не работает

Tags: javascript

Есть код на JS:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}

var modal1 = document.getElementById('myModal1');
var btn1 = document.getElementById("myBtn1");
var span1 = document.getElementsByClassName("close1")[0];

btn1.onclick = function() {
    modal1.style.display = "block";
}

span1.onclick = function() {
    modal1.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal1) {
        modal1.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Проблема в последней части кода:

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal1) {
        modal1.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Если его оставлять, то первое модальное окно можно закрыть только при нажатии на крестик. Если убрать, то наоборот. 1 модальное окно закрывается при клике в любую область, а 2 окно только при нажатии на крестик.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка? Нужно, что бы они работали одинаково. И 1 и 2 окна закрывались и по нажатию на крестик и по нажатию в любую другую область (кроме нажатия на само окно).

HTML 1 окна:

```
<button id="myBtn">Открыть окно</button>
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <h2>Шапка модального окна</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Какой-то текст в теле модального окна</p>
        <p>Ещё другой текст...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <h3>Футер модального окна</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

2 окно:

```
<button id="myBtn1">Открыть окно</button>
  <div id="myModal1" class="modal1">
    <div class="modal1-content">
      <div class="modal1-header">
        <span class="close1">&times;</span>
        <h2>модального окна</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal1-body">
        <p>Какой-то текст в теле модального окна</p>
        <p>Ещё другой текст...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal1-footer">
        <h3>Футер модального окна</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

css:

```
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

#myBtn {
  background-color: #9C27B0;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 180px;
}


.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}


.modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #E1BEE7;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 5px solid #7B1FA2;
    width: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}


@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}


.close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #9C27B0;
    color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #9C27B0;
    color: white;
}

#myBtn1 {
  background-color: #9C27B0;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 180px;
}


.modal1 {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}


.modal1-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #E1BEE7;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 5px solid #7B1FA2;
    width: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}


@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}


.close1 {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close1:hover,
.close1:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal1-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #9C27B0;
    color: white;
}

.modal1-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal1-footer {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #9C27B0;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/981378/256824

Comment: @РустамГимранов добавил код html

Comment: css-a не хватает, чтобы посмотреть.

Comment: @Crus добавил стили

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так вот будет работать правильно. Пример на jsfiddle тут - https://jsfiddle.net/crus/bqfmdcrp/9/

Вы 2 раза подряд вызывали window.onclick, и выполнялся только один.

```
window.onclick = function(e) {
    if (e.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
        console.log('done');
    } else if (e.target == modal1) {
        modal1.style.display = "none";
        console.log('done');
    }
}
```

Comment: Огромнейшее вам спасибо!